# Cant see the IP for my OWASP Broken Web Application (BWA) running in Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: owasp

I imported the OWASP BWA web application image into Virtual Box and started it up.  Its supposed to show me the IP on which I can access my web application.  Instead I see text that states that the web application can be accessed at http:///.  How can I see what IP I can access BWA on?  I have my Network Setting set to Host Only.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem because the VirtualBox dhcp server was disabled for the network that the BWA VM was on.

From the main VirtualBox screen:

File -> Host Network Manager and enable the dhcp server

I only had one network showing and that had the dhcp server disabled. If you have more than  one network, you will have to dig around to figure out which one to enable.

Comment: How to set it on Hyper-V ?

Comment: @Moeez There are a few links. Try this one: https://lemp.io/configuring-a-dhcp-server-on-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine/

Answer (score 1):

**

Resetting the Host network Manager in to this configuration helped me to fix it.

**

[image: Host Network Manager]

[image: Host Network Manager]

Then Restart the instances or

```
service networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem because I created more than one Host-only networks. After deleting till only one left, I started the VM again and it worked.